# list empty in angular when consume api

Tags: angular, api

i am try to consume a api, the 'api' with postman return data, but when i consume from angular the array is empty

My service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, 
           HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ServicioService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      public getAll() {
        let url = 'https://localhost:44388/api/places';
        return this.http.get(url);  
        } 
    }


[it´s the code that use my api][1]
```

[it´s the code that use .ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xkIj.png) of

Comment: How is `getAll()` called?

Comment: getPlaces(){
    let observer = {
      next: x => this.lstPLaces = x,
      error: err => this.serplaceService.handleError(err)
    };
    this.serplaceService.getAll().subscribe(observer)
  }

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to see if it work.

In your service:

```
public getAll() {
    let url = `${environment.base_url}/api/Places`;

    return this.httpC.get(url);
}
```

Then call in your component

```
this.serplaceService.getAll().subscribe(
   (data) => this.lstPLaces = data,
   error => this.error = error
)
```

Note:

> Reading the full response The response body doesn't return all the
>   data you may need. Sometimes servers return special headers or status
>   codes to indicate certain conditions that are important to the
>   application workflow.

Tell HttpClient that you want the full response with the observe option:

```
return this.httpC.get(url, { observe: 'response' });
```

Comment: hi, tank you for you response, i writed the code and the same, when i try to read the varibles after

this.serplaceService.getAll().subscribe(
   (data) => this.lstPLaces = data,
   error => this.error = error
)

the variables this.lstPLaces and this.error are undefined

Comment: how i can send it, the

Comment: where i can send the code, here is very small the space namespace MyTime.ApiControl.Controllers
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using MyTimes.Bl;
    using MyTimes.Common.Models;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq; 

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PlacesController : ControllerBase
    {        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            var lstPlaces = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Place>>(new BLPlaces().FindAll());

Comment: lstPlaces.Remove(lstPlaces.Where(X => X.PlaceId == 0).FirstOrDefault());

            return new JsonResult(lstPlaces);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Can you please update your code in your question. How can i suppose to see that